# instagram api comment response php

Tags: php, instagram-api

i have a problem with api instagram php.
I have try to get a list of comment of my account developer.

I have already try use this instragram-api rest : 
The Instagram comments endpoint https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN

but in the response i read only my comment and not other my follower comment in the media ...
I have tried reset key secret and rebuild a app but not have effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think your apps must be in the Sandbox mode. When the apps in the sandbox mode, it can't read the general public content include the commentator of media. read this https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/